# Красивое отображение строк при запуске плейбука в ansible

Tags: ansible

Запускаю плейбук:

```
ansible-playbook  tailored_project-deploy.yml -i inventory/localhost/1-project  -vv --tags="install_db"
```

В результате в терминал выпадает много полезных логов, но строки идут через запятую в кавычках. Например:

> "INFORMATION: some_product is started", "INFORMATION: directory
>   /home/etp/Projects/Installer_repository/some_product/update_config_1_001
>   not found", "WARNING: file
>   /home/etp/Projects/Installer_repository/some_product/types/list.txt
>   not found"

Можно ли выводить их с новой строки как если бы питоновский скрипт (именно его дёргает таск в плейбуке) выполнялся сам по себе через терминал, то есть каждая строка с новой строки? А то не шибко читабельно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант решения:

```
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=minimal ansible-playbook  tailored_project-deploy.yml -i inventory/localhost/1-project  -vv --tags="install_db"
```